# Play video inside WhatsApp from URL

Tags: android, html, video-streaming, whatsapp

WhatsApp supports playing videos using URLs, for example, YouTube videos or Facebook videos. The user doesn't need to navigate to the specific app.

I want to implement the same feature in my app, when a user shares the URL of the video, it should play inside WhatsApp. But I didn't find any suitable documentation or references.

However I tried following [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/), I couldn't play video on WhatsApp, it can only display title and description along with URL.

Here is a sample of what I have implemented.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta property="og:video" content="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" />

  <title>Test video title</title>
</head>
<body>
  Video description
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think It is the other direction... youtube is not doing anything to be directly playable in Whatsapp. It is the Whatsapp client, that recognizes a Youtube-URL and displays a player for it. I am not aware of a generic format that you can use but I might be wrong.